# MongoDB Aggregate Facet & Group

Tags: javascript, reactjs, mongodb

I have the following dataset which I am looking to summarize within a report. Basically I am looking for status count (by status) and group for each key. I have tried several ways to completing this to no avail.

```
[
  {
    "_id": ObjectId("635f808302d5f6cb7c293298"),
    "key": "scientific",
    "custom_properties": [
      {
        "namespace": "common metadata",
        "key": "status",
        "scope": "public",
        "value": "To be uploaded",
        "inherited": null
      },
      {
        "namespace": "common metadata",
        "key": "version",
        "scope": "public",
        "value": "1.0",
        "inherited": null
      },
      {
        "namespace": "common metadata",
        "key": "start date",
        "scope": "public",
        "value": "1642550400000",
        "inherited": null
      },
    ]
  },
  {
    "_id": ObjectId("635f809d02d5f6cb7c29353c"),
    "key": "contracts",
    "custom_properties": [
      {
        "namespace": "common metadata",
        "key": "status",
        "scope": "public",
        "value": "To be reviewed",
        "inherited": null
      },
      {
        "namespace": "common metadata",
        "key": "version",
        "scope": "public",
        "value": "",
        "inherited": null
      },
      {
        "namespace": "contracts",
        "key": "expiry date",
        "scope": "public",
        "value": "",
        "inherited": null
      },
      {
        "namespace": "common metadata",
        "key": "start date",
        "scope": "public",
        "value": "",
        "inherited": null
      },
    ]
  },
  {
    "_id": ObjectId("635f80a002d5f6cb7c293588"),
    "key": "contracts",
    "custom_properties": [
      {
        "namespace": "common metadata",
        "key": "status",
        "scope": "public",
        "value": "To be uploaded",
        "inherited": null
      },
      {
        "namespace": "common metadata",
        "key": "version",
        "scope": "public",
        "value": "",
        "inherited": null
      },
    ]
  }
]
```

and I am looking to Group and Facet, I am uncertain as to which to complete first.

The desired output should summarize the status count and group by key, and should look similar to the following...

```
[
 {
  scientific: [{
    'To be reviewed': 0,
    'To be uploaded': 1   
  }],
  contracts: [{
    'To be reviewed': 1,
    'To be uploaded': 1
  }], 
}
]
```

NOTE: both the keys and status values are dynamic. I.e. we could introduce a new status, and there will be several keys introduced over time.

Comment: In the requested result, why are the objects inside an array?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this with the following pipeline:

All this requires is a couple of `$group` stages to count, then some structure manipulation to get the required output

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    $group: {
      _id: {
        key: "$key",
        statusVal: {
          "$getField": {
            "field": "value",
            "input": {
              "$arrayElemAt": [
                {
                  $filter: {
                    input: "$custom_properties",
                    cond: {
                      $eq: [
                        "$$this.key",
                        "status"
                      ]
                    }
                  }
                },
                0
              ]
            },
            
          }
        }
      },
      sum: {
        $sum: 1
      }
    }
  },
  {
    $group: {
      _id: "$_id.key",
      types: {
        $push: {
          k: "$_id.statusVal",
          v: "$sum"
        }
      }
    }
  },
  {
    $group: {
      _id: null,
      root: {
        $push: {
          k: "$_id",
          v: {
            "$arrayToObject": "$types"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  {
    $replaceRoot: {
      newRoot: {
        "$arrayToObject": "$root"
      }
    }
  }
])
```

[Mongo Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/4I2uMNqjvC6)